# How to fill series in the column of excel after skipping the cell (s) which already have some text

Tags: excel

I want to fill series in a column and skip those cell which has some values (text).

In the attached screenshot, I want to fill series in the Student ID column.  skip those cell which has already text or the row is merged and fill the series.

See the result I want:

[image: Click on link to see the result I want]

Comment: What are you starting with? What information do you want to put in a column, where there's a blank space? It's unclear from your post, could you please describe a little more? Also, what have you tried so far? Do you want a formula, or VBA solution? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In column C (Student ID), you can see number is filled. I have a large sheet in which some rows are added due to this sequence of id got incorrect. So, I want to correct the numbers (Student ID) by some formula. If there is no row which contains text. I can do it easily that is by dragging and dropping. Since there is some text also in the student id column, I cant do that

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to copy a formula down in ColumnC (without deleting the name data) but could handle that with an [IF](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) statement in a helper column. Assuming you start with what is shown in ColumnC in the image, F2 (for example) could contain:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)),C2,MAX(F$1:F1)+1)
```

which may be copied up one cell and down to suit.

[image: SO41178202 example]